# template.find().val gives me undefined value

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a template form to input and show values, the template is like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
   <input class="form-control" type="text"  id = "apFirstName" 
      value= {{#each apprentice}}{{name.firstName}}{{/each}}>
</div>
```

The js code looks like this:

```
Template.apprenticeProfile.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();            
        first = template.find('#apFirstName').val;
        console.log(first);
```

The console will give me undefined, but before my code works if I change the input

`id = 'apFirstName'`  to  `name = 'apFirstName'`

and the js like this

```
Template.apprenticeProfile.events({
    'submit form': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let first = $('[name=apFirstName]').val();
        console.log(first);
```

Could anyone tell me what's going wrong with my template.find().val code? And If possible, is there any way template.find().val can work on  `name = 'apFirstName'`  instead of change name to id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you require a jQuery element or JavaScript element? If you want jQuery element them you should use [`template.$`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_$) like this,

```
Template.apprenticeProfile.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();            
        first = template.$('#apFirstName').val(); //use val() instead of val
        console.log(first);
     }
});
```

If you want javascript element then

```
Template.apprenticeProfile.events({
    'submit form': function(event,template) {
        event.preventDefault();            
        first = template.find('#apFirstName').value; //use value instead of val
        console.log(first);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the javascript way and works for me.